# Recover the privileges of the admin user of DSpace

Tags: administrator, dspace

Editing permissions of a collection, by mistake we have removed all the privileges of the admin user (currently only belongs to the Anonymous group). Is it possible to recover the privileges of this user? Or create a new administrator user with all permissions over all communities and collections?
We use version 3.2 of DSpace.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in DSpace that is being tracked by the following ticket: https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-2687

You will need to re-create group 1.

```
dspace=> insert into epersongroup values(1,'Administrator'); 
INSERT 0 1
```

You can then use the .../bin/dspace create-administrator command to re-add users to that group.

Answer (score 5):

You can always create a new administrator with the command line utility `bin/dspace create-administrator`
You could also move your user back to the Administrator group (it's the group with id 1). But you'll probably need another administrator to do that in the first place.

I don't know if there is a way to find all the groups an eperson used to be in.